# Error con operaciones aritméticas usando variables: "orden no encontrada"

Tags: bash

Estoy comenzando con Bash. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme ya que no se que estoy haciendo mal, estoy realizando un programa que calcula la potencia de un numero introduciendo por teclado la base y el exponente. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Introducza Base: ";read base
echo "Introducza Exponente: ";read exponente
resultado=1
for ((num=0;num<$exponente;num+=1))
do
       $resultado = $(( $resultado * $base ))
done
echo "Resultado " $resultado
```

El error me lo da en la línea:

```
$resultado = $(( $resultado * $base ))
```

donde me dice lo siguiente:

> ./ejercicio9.sh: línea 8: 1: orden no encontrada

No sé si es problema de sintaxis espacios, etc.

Comment: Te recomiendo este sitio para verificar tus scripts: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No pueden haber espacios en la operación, pues Bash lo interpreta como un argumento.

Además, como dice @cnbandicoot si colocas el $ delante de la variable intentarás imprimirlo en lugar de guardarlo, igual que no lo usas cuando en las primeras lineas usas el comando `read`.

En el bucle no importa si imprimes la variable $exponente o usas su valor sin el $.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Introducza Base: ";read base
echo "Introducza Exponente: ";read exponente
resultado=1
for ((num=0;num<$exponente;num+=1))
do
       resultado=$(($resultado*$base))
done
echo "Resultado " $resultado
```

Answer (score -2):

El problema viene dado porque al usar `$resultado =`, internamente estás imprimiendo el `$resultado`, en vez de asignarle un valor. Por lo que deberás hacer:

```
resultado = $(( $resultado * $base ))
```

Comment: Eso también te daría error por los espacios al alrededor del `=`. Necesitas `variable=valor` y no `variable = valor`.